# VBA code to do loop of transposing multiple data from single column

Tags: excel

I have thousands of data in a single column and I want to transpose these to a different sheet, I have added a number for each type of data in the column, it looks like this
so I want the code to copy and paste as transposed to another sheet then start again to the next row after 0.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

I would make a "for each" loop and test for each line the type's number of the information. Then following the number copy and paste it in the right sheet. To know on which line you need to paste, you can have a long variable in each sheet to increment for each paste. Or you can use ".End(xlUp).Row" to know the last cell of the column.

Comment: thank you for replying... however I'm every new to to using macros and I'm not sure how to start with the info you given... this is the code that I'm using right now... Sub Macro5()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Dashboard")

    With Worksheets("RawData").Range("a1:a14")

        ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count) = _
          Application.Transpose(.Value)
        .ClearContents
        .Parent.Parent.Save

    End With

End Sub

Comment: Sorry, I didn't well understood the first time but now it's ok, I think I understood what you want to do ! (You want a column 1,2,3... in another sheet with corresponding information right ?)
You can first loop on the first sheet : 
dim i as integer (or long)
dim n as integer
For i = 1 to 1000
n = cells(i,1)
select case n
case 1
paste in sheet2 column 1
case 2
paste in sheet2 column 2
case ...
paste in sheet2 column ...
next